# Why is the electric field of a naturally equilibrating, isotropic, cylindrical conductor not a function of z (height)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, special-functions, bessel-functions, electromagnetism

**Some math is presented below to make the question more specific.**

**TL;DR:** If you calculate the electric field of a solid, cylindrical conductor, you find that this field is only a function of radius and time (unless I made a mistake with the calculation, presented below for the curious). Why is there no $z$ dependence? What mistake(s), if any, lie in the solution below?

**Also, as a follow-on question:** how does one obtain/determine the initial conditions of the field, in order to perform a Fourier-Bessel series summation and gain a solution that is consistent with said initial conditions?

---

**Background:**

Maxwell's equations are a set of four differential equations that completely describe classical electromagnetic phenomena in S.I. Units.

**Equations of $3\text{D}$ position and time:**
\begin{eqnarray}
\textbf{Div} [E] &=& \dfrac{p}{e} \tag{i}\\
\textbf{Curl}[E] &=& -\dfrac{dB}{dt} \tag{ii}\\
\textbf{Div} [B] &=& 0 \tag{iii}\\
\textbf{Curl}[B] &=& uJ + ue\dfrac{dE}{dt} \tag{iv}
\end{eqnarray}
Where
\begin{eqnarray}
1&.& E \,\,\text{is the electric field vector},\\
2&.& B \,\,\text{is the magnetic field vector},\\
3&.& J \,\,\text{is the free current density field vector},\\
4&.& e \,\,\text{is the electric permeability of the material},\\
5&.& u \,\,\text{is the magnetic permeability of the material},\\
6&.& p \,\,\text{is the free charge density}.
\end{eqnarray}
**Situation:**

Given a simple, homogeneous, solid, cylindrical conductor (i.e. $e$ and $u$ are constants), the natural question of the distribution of current (what does $J$ look like?) arises.

**Setting up the problem:**

The conductor is aligned in the $z$-axis direction, and neither of the fields are driven (not forced to behave in a given way). Find $E$, while assuming that the conductor is simple.

We define:
$$J = \sigma E$$
which is a material constraint suggesting that the current density is directly proportional to the electric field, and the proportionality is ensured by a constant $\sigma$, which is the metal's conductivity. This form of $J$ implies that our conductor is isotropic and linear.

**MY attempt at a solution:**

$$\textbf{Curl}[(ii)] = \textbf{Curl}[\textbf{Curl}[E]] = \textbf{Grad}[\textbf{Div}[E]] - \Delta[E] = -\dfrac{d}{dt}(\textbf{Curl}[B]) \tag{v}$$

But from $\text{(iv)}$,

$$\textbf{Curl}[B] = uJ + ue\dfrac{dE}{dt} = u\sigma E + ue\dfrac{dE}{dt} \tag{vi}$$

We can plug $\text{(vi)}$ into $\textbf{Curl}[B]$ in equation $\text{(v)}$, and get:
$$Grad[Div[E]] - \Delta[E] = -\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(u\sigma E + ue\dfrac{dE}{dt}\right)$$
$$\Delta[E] - \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(u\sigma E + ue\dfrac{dE}{dt}\right) = \textbf{Grad}[\textbf{Div}[E]]\tag{(vii)}$$

**Brief Discussion of Grad[Div[E]].**

Taking the Divergence of (iv), we get:

> Div[Curl[B]] = Div[u*J + u*e*dE/dt]
>
> 0 = u*Div[J] + u*e*d/dt(Div[E])

But J = sigma*E, so

> u*sigma*Div[E] = -u*e*d/dt(Div[E])

From (i), Div[E] = p/e, so...

> sigma*p/e = -e*d/dt(p/e)
>
> (sigma/e)*p + dp/dt = 0

**This is a basic 1st order linear ode, and the solution is:**

p(r,t) = p0*e^(-t/tau), where tau = e/sigma, and p0 = p(r,0) is our arbitrary boundary condition.

> Note: We don't actually know the spatial distribution of p, but we
>   know that it decays exponentially, on the time-scale of tau. Since
>   p(r,t) decays to zero in "almost no time at-all", the common
>   approximation is:
>
> Div[E] = p(r,t)/e -> 0 .. this works for engineering applications, but
>   as I am seeking an analytical solution, I will not make this
>   approximation, because then I lose the spatial distribution
>   information of p(r,0).

*Thus Grad[Div[E]] is not approximated as zero on the timescale of tau.*

**Back to the solution:**

> We make the assumption that vector E is oriented exclusively in the
>   z-axis direction, and travels along the axis of the conductor. Also,
>   we will investigate the form of E(r,t) in cylindrical coordinates
>   (r,T,z), because this appeals to the geometry of the problem.

*z-axis direction of E vector:*

> Laplacian[E] = 1/r*(r*d/dr(E_z))' + 1/(r^2)*d^2/dT^2(E_z) +
>   d^2/dz^2(E_z)

and...

> Grad[Div[E]] = Grad[d/dz(E_z)] = d/dr(d/dz(E_z)) (r) +
>   1/r*d/dT(d/dz(E_z)) (T) + d^2/dz^2(E_z) (z)

, where (r),(T),(z) are directional vectors.

**Notice that this geometry imposes the following constraints:**

> 1. d/dr(d/dz(E_z)) (r) = 0
> 2. 1/r*d/dT(d/dz(E_z)) (T) = 0

Thus;

> Laplacian[E] - d/dt(u*sigma*E + u*e*dE/dt) = Grad[Div[E]] ... (vii)
>
> 1/r*(r*d/dr(E_z))' + 1/(r^2)*d^2/dT^2(E_z) + d^2/dz^2(E_z) -
>   d/dt(u*sigma*E + u*e*dE/dt) = d^2/dz^2(E_z)
>
> 1/r*(r*d/dr(E_z))' + 1/(r^2)*d^2/dT^2(E_z) - d/dt(u*sigma*E +
>   u*e*dE/dt) = 0 ...(viii)

**Assumption: The Current density does not have a preferred mode i.e. it is rotationally invariant.** This implies....

> E(r,T,t) = E(r,t)

And the theta (T) second partial term of (viii) becomes zero, prompting:

> 1/r*(r*d/dr(E_z))' - d/dt(u*sigma*E + u*e*dE/dt) = 0 ...(ix)

Expanding (ix), we get:

> d^2/dr^2(E_z) + 1/r*d/dr(E_z) - u*sigma*d/dt(E_z) - u*e*d^2/dt^2(E_z)
>   = 0

**Employ separation of variables:**

> E(r,t) = R(r)*N(t),
>
> N*R" + 1/r*N*R' - u*sigma*R*N' - u*e*R*N" = 0
>
> R"/R + 1/r*R'/R - u*sigma*N'/N - u*e*N"/N = 0
>
> R"(r)/R(r) + 1/r*R'(r)/R(r) = u*sigma*N'(t)/N(t) + u*e*N"(t)/N(t) =
>   -lambda ...(x)

lambda is a constant parameter (the eigenvalue). Notice that the units of lambda are [1/m^2], implying that it is a *square spatial frequency*.

Rearranging the R(r) based equation from (x), we get:

> r^2*R"(r) + r*R'(r) + lambda*r^2*R(r) = 0

*which is the a parametric Bessel equation of order 0.*

> There are many ways to solve this equation, but the Frobenius method
>   of searching for a solution using a convergent power series is,
>   perhaps, the most straight-forward approach. Doing this,
>
> we end up with a power-series representation of:

**R(r) = J[0,Sqrt[lambda]*r]**.

> I choose not to prove this here, but it's pretty straightforward.
>
> Now, our current is confined to the conductor, meaning the current
>   density is zero for r > L, where L is the radius of our cylindrical
>   conductor. As such, we can establish a boundary condition. We choose
>   to solve for E such that the current density at surface is zero. *In
>   practice, this makes sense because the skin of the conductor is thin
>   enough to have an infinite effective resistance. The surface would
>   need to have an infinite conductivity to transport current in an
>   infinitesimally thin layer of the conductor.*

Thus: R(L) = 0 ...our chosen boundary condition.

Since R(r) = J[0,Sqrt[lambda]*r], we need to find a specific eigenvalue of lambda such that R[L] = 0.

Since J[0,r] has an infinite set of roots (p_j) that all tend to infinity, we will suppose that one of those roots satisfies the boundary condition. Of course, we don't know which one.

So:

> R[L] = J[0,p_j] = J[0,Sqrt[lambda]*L]

invoking the relationship: Sqrt[lambda] = p_j/L, so the eigenvalue lambda is:

**lambda = (p_j/L)^2, and R[r] = J[0,p_j/L*r].**

Thus (picking the second equation from (x)):

> u*sigma*N'(t)/N(t) + u*e*N"(t)/N(t) = -lambda
>
> u*sigma*N'(t)/N(t) + u*e*N"(t)/N(t) = -(p_j/L)^2
>
> u*e*N"(t) + u*sigma*N'(t) + (p_j/L)^2*N(t) = 0

**Which is a simple 2nd order linear ode of constant coefficients.**

We then get the two independent solutions:

**N(t) = e^(-t/(2*tau))*[K1*e^(t/tq) + K2*e^(-t/tq)]**

Where:

tq = (2*u*e)/Sqrt[(u*sigma)^2 - 4*(u*e)*p_j/L] [seconds]

*N(t) is therefore dampened at twice the rate of the relaxation frequency, but is subject to the term tq, which may be a real exponential or generally complex sinusoid.*

**Thus, it follows that without driving/exciting the fields of the conductor in any way:**

> E(r,t) = N*(t)*R(r) = J[0,Sqrt[lambda]*L]*e^(-t/(2*tau))*[K1*e^(t/tq)
>   + K2*e^(-t/tq)].

*A few things bother me about this natural equilibration solution:*

> 1. there is no z-dependence on the electric field
> 2. The constraints suggest that d/dz(E_z) = 0 which supports this view. WHY?
> 3. I did not calculate the p_j root(s) from the Bessel-Fourier series because I did not know the starting dynamics i.e. E(r,0) and
>      d/dt(E(r,t))|(t=0). Can I infer this information from the Maxwell's
>      equations or not?

**So, my question again:**

"Why is the electric field of a naturally equilibrating, isotropic, cylindrical conductor not a function of z (height)?"

Thank you for helping me understand this result. I'm new to the Stack-exchange and
might have written in a form that's unusual and plain bad (my apologies). I hope you can help me understand the interpretation of this bit of math.

-Oswald.

Comment: Hi. I edited part of your post, it was so long and if it isn't as you wanted, you can _rollback_, sorry!

Comment: @MyGlasses On the contrary, I appreciate your edit, and yeah, it's a pretty long post. Thanks. :) Hopefully you'll have some insight on the result.

Comment: I didn’t read through all of this, but what is the length of your conductor? If your answer to my question is *infinite,* that’s also the answer to your question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I couldn't specify a length in the solution because the d^2/dz^2(E_z) (k) terms cancel out. It seems that solving the equations the way I did is akin to saying the conductor is formed by some process and we begin to investigate the exponential decay of the field strength of the E field right after said formation. Basically, there's a time t=0 for the charge distribution and since in reality ref. t is >0, the Div[E] term is zero, even though time is assumed to be affine. So the charges 'learn' what z is what viii the passage of time and addition of forcing functions for E. Maybe?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft my insanity makes a bit more sense if you read the whole solution. Thank you for your perspective. :)

Comment: please follow the guidelines outlined by [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1)

Comment: It seems that prompting Div[E] = Div[E_z] = d/dz[E_z] forces d/dz[E_z] = p/e, which is weird because it implies that our charge is driven externally, and in such a way as to always correct for z-sensitive discrepancies in the field. What if p/e != d/dz[E_z]? I think that last rhetorical question makes sense of the z-independent result.

So now I am curious: if Div[E_z] = d/dz[E_z] and Div[E] = Div[E_z] = p/e, how is it that p/e drives the system via d/dz[E_z] if p/e is an external function that is inconsequential throughout the solution?